# Converting Arduino Library to Visual C++ dll

Tags: c++, arduino

Hey all I am trying my best to fixed these few errors below. The C++ code is from an Arduino library that i wanted to convert to Visual C++ dll for use in one of my C# applications.

These are the areas that have the errors:

```
void AES::do_aes_encrypt(BYTE *plain,int size_p,BYTE *cipher,BYTE *key, int bits, BYTE ivl [N_BLOCK]){
  calc_size_n_pad(size_p);
  BYTE plain_p[get_size()];
  padPlaintext(plain,plain_p);
  int blocks = get_size() / N_BLOCK;
  set_key(key, bits) ;
  cbc_encrypt(plain_p, cipher, blocks, ivl);
}
```

The "**BYTE plain_p[get_size()];**" has the error of "**'this' cannot be used in a constant expression**".

```
string AES::letsDecrypt(BYTE *key, string msg, AES aes) {
  char data_decoded[200];
  char iv_decoded[200];
  char temp[200];
  BYTE out[200];

  aes.set_key(key, sizeof(key));
  msg.toCharArray(temp, 200);
  int b64len = base64_decode(data_decoded, temp, msg.length());
  string(iv_Encoded).toCharArray(temp, 200);

  base64_decode(iv_decoded, temp, string(iv_Encoded).length());  
  aes.do_aes_decrypt((BYTE *)data_decoded, b64len, out, key, 128, (BYTE *)iv_decoded);
  char message[msg.length()];
  char* msgBase64 = (char *)out;

  base64_decode(message, (char *)out, msg.length());

  return std::string(message);
}
```

The "**msg.toCharArray(temp, 200);**" has the error of "**class "std::basic_string, std::allocator>" has no member "toCharArray"**".

Another error on the same code above "**char message[msg.length()];**" has the error of "**expression must have a constant value**".

Help would be great since I'm new to the C++ side!

Comment: I strongly recommend learning the language before trying to port code between languages. `toCharArray` is not a member of `std::string`. You could use a combination of `msg.c_str()` and `strcpy_s` and, but why bother when you can pass the `msg.data()` directly to `base64_decode`?

Comment: `char message[msg.length()];` would be valid in C, but C++ is not C. in C++ an array must have a constant size. Some compilers bend this rule with an extension to the C++ Standard, but Visual Studio adhered to the Standard.

Comment: @user4581301 Would changing the signatures of `get_size()` and `length()` to `constexpr int get_size()`, etc ... fix these errors?

Comment: @jackw11111 The point of those size-getting functions is they return values that you don't know ahead of time. That eliminates `const` and `constexpr`. My recommendation is to use `std::string` throughout and forget about arrays for this job.